# Bind Row or Cell Background color to a Property of the Object displayed in the row in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, binding

I Have a TableView which Displays a List of Activities. I want the background color of one of the Cells of the Row or the whole Row to be binded to the ObjectProperty color of my Activity, since i want my user to be able to select the appearance color of the Row. I tried several approaches like a RowFactory, but i couldnt find a solution for binding it to changing data Propertys. If that isnt possible, a hack to change the color somehow would also be great. Thanks :)

```
public class Activity {

private final StringProperty description;
private final StringProperty customer;
private final StringProperty project;
private final IntegerProperty duration;
private final StringProperty city;
private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dueDate;
private final ObjectProperty<Color> color;
```

Where i set the Cell Values:

```
  @FXML
private void initialize() {
    // Initialize the activity table with the two columns.
    descriptionColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().DescriptionProperty()
    );
    projectColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().projectProperty());
    setUpDragAndDrop();
    // Listen for selection changes and show the activity details when changed.
    activityTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
            (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> showActivityDetails(newValue));
}
```

The Data:

```
    public ObservableList<Activity> activityData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Comment: Post [mre] please

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
activityTable.setRowFactory(t -> new TableRow<>() {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Activity activity, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(activity, empty);
        styleProperty().unbind();
        if (empty) {
            setStyle("");
        } else {
            styleProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> 
                "-fx-background: "+formatColorString(activity.getColor()),
                activity.colorProperty()
            ));
        }
    }

    private String formatColorString(Color color) {
        int r = (int) (color.getRed()   * 255) ;
        int g = (int) (color.getGreen() * 255) ;
        int b = (int) (color.getBlue()  * 255) ;
        return String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your example works! Just out of curiosity: Should it not be *-fx-background-color* instead of *-fx-background*?

Comment: @anko By default, `-fx-background-color` is set to `-fx-background`, however setting `-fx-background` will ensure a suitable colour is used for any text as well.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked :) I Dont 100% understand how it works so ill ask another question: So the Tableview contains my Observable List and since that List contains Activities the Tableview UpdateItem Method knows how to get the specific Activity in that Row and i dont have to write any code to link both of them?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [James_D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62376677/13561971): When you want to change the background color of one column type only (instead of the whole row):

```
descriptionColumn.setCellFactory(column -> new TableCell<>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        styleProperty().unbind();
        if (item == null || empty) {
            setText("");
            setStyle("");
        } else {
            setText(item);

            Activity activity = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());

            styleProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() ->
                            "-fx-background-color: " + formatColorString(activity.getColor()),
                    activity.colorProperty()
            ));
        }
    }
});
```